# Como buscar palavras chaves em um Json

Tags: php

Eu tenho um JSON me retornando os seguintes campos:

```
{
 "titulo": 'Primeiro contato',
 "texto": 'Olá gostaria de fazer uma sugestão para vocês'
}
```

Eu estou tentando fazer a seguinte verificação

```
foreach ($data as $msg) {
                $titulo = $msg->titulo;
                $texto = $msg->texto;
                $termo = 'contato';

            if (strpos( $titulo , $termo) === false) {
                echo 'Não encontrado';
             } else {
                echo 'Encontrado';
             }
}
```

Deste modo ele me retorna somente as palavras do titulo e procura apenas uma palavra por vez. Eu quero procurar mais de uma palavra tanto no titulo quanto no texto da msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um for para percorrer um array com as palavras chave

```
    foreach ($data as $msg) {
            $titulo = $msg->titulo;
            $texto = $msg->texto;
            $termo = ["contato", "sugestão"];
            $count = count($termo);

        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
            $pos = stripos( $titulo , $termo[$i]);
            $pos2 = stripos($texto , $termo[$i]);
            if (($pos !== false ) || ($pos2 !== false)) {
                echo "Encontrado."
             } else {
                echo "Não Encontrado."
             }
        }

    }
```